# Turning a vector into a matrix

Tags: r

I have a vector of 5 values as follows containing different months as follows:

```
[July August September October November]
```

How do I get these into a matrix form as follows.

```
[July August September October November]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0    ]
[0,    1,       0,       0,       0    ]
[0,    0,       1,       0,       0    ]
[0,    0,       0,       1,       0    ]
[0,    0,       0,       0,       1    ]
```

Additionally I have another vector I would like to append on the end so then the output would look like this.

```
[July August September October November Other]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0,      50 ]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0,      30 ]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0,      60 ]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0,      22 ]
[1,    0,       0,       0,       0,      5  ]
```

Comment: You can check with `?model.matrix` or just table `table(seq_along(v1), v1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table` with the sequence of vector and the vector itself.  If the order of month names needs to be maintained, convert it to a `factor` with `levels` specified by the `intersect` of `unique` elements of vector and the `month.name`

```
tbl <- table(seq_along(v1), v2, dnn = NULL)
tbl
#   July August September October November
#1    1      0         0       0        0
#2    0      1         0       0        0
#3    0      0         1       0        0
#4    0      0         0       1        0
#5    0      0         0       0        1
```

Now, we can append with second `vector`

```
cbind(tbl, Other)
```

---

Or using `model.matrix`

```
model.matrix(~ v2 - 1, data = data.frame(v2))
```

---

Or using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(v2)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("July", "August", "September", "October", "November")
v2 <- factor(v1, levels = intersect(month.name, unique(v1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(v1, function(x) as.numeric(v1 == x))
#     July August September October November
#[1,]    1      0         0       0        0
#[2,]    0      1         0       0        0
#[3,]    0      0         1       0        0
#[4,]    0      0         0       1        0
#[5,]    0      0         0       0        1
```

Comment: Outer `+(outer(v1, v1, "=="))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.matrix` or `dummyVars` also

## Data:

```
v1 <- c("July", "August", "September", "October", "November")
v1 <- as.data.frame(v1)
```

## Model.Matrix:

```
v2 <- data.frame(v1 = v1)
as.data.frame(model.matrix(~.-1, v1))
  v1August v1July v1November v1October v1September
1        0      1          0         0           0
2        1      0          0         0           0
3        0      0          0         0           1
4        0      0          0         1           0
5        0      0          1         0           0
```

## DummyVars approach:

```
library(caret)
m1 <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = v1)
data.frame(predict(m1, newdata = v1))
  v1.August v1.July v1.November v1.October v1.September
1         0       1           0          0            0
2         1       0           0          0            0
3         0       0           0          0            1
4         0       0           0          1            0
5         0       0           1          0            0
```